# Please help me figure out why this transaction is not confirmed?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

Please help me figure out why this transaction is not confirmed?8f62acf0f0ddc3e38db2e8ec2755f4e54aa5bf616d685e2f3361155fc9d44125

Answer (score 0):

The fee paid on this transaction is well below the value being paid on recent transactions added to blocks.
The fees being paid to enter a block at the time of writing this reply are about 25-30sat/vB minimum. The fees paid by that transaction are 10sat/vB.

To confirm the transaction you should use some mechanism to increase the fees, either [RBF](https://bitcoinops.org/en/topics/replace-by-fee/) or [CPFP](https://bitcoinops.org/en/topics/cpfp/).